# how to remove array filed with value null after unset in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I had unset an array field, in mongo but it's leave the field with valué null,

the question is, how to remove it!

like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2WiV.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could remove all `null` elements from the array with the `$pull` operation.
[See docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Code example:

```
db.collecton.update({condition: "x"}, {$pull: {state: null}});
```

Comment: in this case, I have try like this one : db.tbl_location.update({country:"Indonesia"},
 {$pull:{province:0}});
But it's not work, please check it

Comment: In the $pull condition you have to set the value that should be removed from the array not the index. So in you're case `{$pull:{province:null}}`. NOTE: This removes ALL `null` values from the array.